# MINIMUM on second column, take first and third

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @Foo TABLE (Id INT, PozId INT, Val INT)
        INSERT @Foo (Id, PozId, Val)
        VALUES
        (1, 1, 34),
        (1, 2, 976),
        (2, 1, 235),
        (2, 2, 792),
        (3, 2, 456),
        (3, 3, 123)
```

How to get results like this from above query?

```
(1, 1, 34)
(2, 1, 235)
(3, 2, 456)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This brings you desired result. Query partitions your Ids and picks lowest PozitionId.

```
DECLARE @Foo TABLE
(
    Id INT, PozId INT, Val INT
);

INSERT @Foo
    (Id, PozId, Val)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 34)
    , (1, 2, 976)
    , (2, 1, 235)
    , (2, 2, 792)
    , (3, 2, 456)
    , (3, 3, 123);

SELECT Id, PozId, Val
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY PozId) AS RowNo, *
    FROM @Foo
    ) AS T
WHERE RowNo = 1;
```

Comment: Superb answer, could you also write solution for 2005 sql server?

Comment: @Maleowy The query works just fine in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson the query works in sql server 2005, the insert doesn't because of the keyword VALUES. However it doesn't matter since the question is tagged sql server 20008